# Rotate canvas keyevent

Tags: javascript, events, canvas

How can I rotate a canvas triangle using a keydown event?

For example if I create a triangle like this:

```
function drawTriangle(){

    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(x,y)
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(-50, 50);
    ctx.lineTo(50, 50);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
```

Where do I code the rotation? Inside of the keydown event function?

Like, when I press the  right arrow the triangle should go right, when press left triangle goes left, up and down the same.

Thanks.

Comment: That all depends on how you're planning to rotate it. If you're just rotating the triangle, if you're rotating the whole screen, *where* you intend to rotate about, etc.

Comment: Rotate just the triangle, like if I press the right arrow key the triangle moves to right, if I press left key, the triangle moves to left. Down and Up same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to first translate the canvas to the point you wish to rotate around, perform the rotation, then undo the translation. The following will rotate around the top of the triangle (you'll see that I'm using `x` and `y` as the origin point for the rotation)

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let x = 50;
let y = 50;
let angle = 0;

function drawTriangle() {
  ctx.save();

  // Move to the point you wish to rotate around
  ctx.translate(x, y);
  // Rotate to the desired angle
  ctx.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180);
  // Undo the initial translation
  ctx.translate(-x, -y);

  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(-50, 50);
  ctx.lineTo(50, 50);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  const delta = 2;
  // Rotate the triangle with the left and right arrow keys
  if (e.key === 'ArrowLeft') {
    angle -= delta;
  } else if (e.key === 'ArrowRight') {
    angle += delta;
  }

  // Move around the triangle with wasd
  if (e.key === 'a') {
    x -= delta;
  } else if (e.key === 'd') {
    x += delta;
  } else if (e.key === 'w') {
    y -= delta;
  } else if (e.key === 's') {
    y += delta;
  }

  // Keep the angle between 0 and 360
  if (angle < 0) {
    angle += 360;
  }
  angle = (angle % 360);

  // Make sure to clear the canvas so we don't get a bunch
  // of triangles drawn over each other
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawTriangle();
});

drawTriangle();
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

canvas {
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="320" height="240"></canvas>
```

Just for fun, I wrote a version with smoother controls.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let x = 50;
let y = 50;
const width = 100;
const height = 50;
let angle = 0;

function drawTriangle() {
  ctx.save();

  // Move to the point you wish to rotate around
  // Go to the center of the triangle
  ctx.translate(x, y + height / 2);
  // Rotate to the desired angle
  ctx.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180);
  // Undo the initial translation
  ctx.translate(-x, -y - height / 2);

  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(-width / 2, height);
  ctx.lineTo(width / 2, height);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
}

const keyMap = {};
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  keyMap[e.key] = true;
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  keyMap[e.key] = false;
});

function updatePosition(deltaTime) {
  const pixelsPerSecond = 50;
  const delta = pixelsPerSecond * deltaTime;
  
  if (keyMap.a) {
    x -= delta;
  }
  if (keyMap.d) {
    x += delta;
  }
  if (keyMap.w) {
    y -= delta;
  }
  if (keyMap.s) {
    y += delta;
  }
  
  // Prevent if from going off screen
  const leftSide = x - width / 2;
  const rightSide = x + width / 2;
  const topSide = y;
  const bottomSide = y + height;
  
  if (leftSide < 0) {
    x = width / 2;
  }
  if (rightSide > canvas.width) {
    x = canvas.width - width / 2;
  }
  if (topSide < 0) {
    y = 0;
  }
  if (bottomSide > canvas.height) {
    y = canvas.height - height;
  }
}

function updateRotation(deltaTime) {
  const degreesPerSecond = 45;
  const delta = degreesPerSecond * deltaTime;
  
  if (keyMap.ArrowLeft) {
    angle -= delta;
  }
  if (keyMap.ArrowRight) {
    angle += delta;
  }

  // Keep the angle between 0 and 360
  if (angle < 0) {
    angle += 360;
  }
  angle = (angle % 360);
}

let prevTime = new Date();
function update() {
  let now = new Date();
  let deltaTime = (now - prevTime) / 1000;
  
  updatePosition(deltaTime);
  updateRotation(deltaTime);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawTriangle();
  prevTime = now;
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

canvas {
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="320" height="240"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks! In your first answer any key what I press after pressed the arrow, will rotate the triangle. How to move the triangle instead of just rotate?

Comment: @AndersonTrugilio Press A to move to the left, D to move to the right, W moves up and D moves down

Comment: Hey Mike, and there is a way to limit the movement inside the canvas? To avoid the triangle to leave the canvas?

Comment: Sure, any time you changed `x` or `y`, just make sure they don't exceed certain values. For example, if `x` ever dips below 50, set it to 50. If `y` ever goes below 0, set it to 0. Same idea for the other edges. You'll have to use the size of the canvas as a reference point.

Comment: I added some code to my "just for fun" section that does this. It does not make sure that it stays within the area when the triangle is rotated. That requires some math that's outside of the scope of this question.